# Mysql database option does not appear in VS 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to connect Mysql for getting data from tables I created in MySql ,with Visual Studio 2015,but when I follow the steps for doing it,there is no option to connect with 'MySql database',why it is happening?

Comment: What options are available?

Comment: Did you install MySQL for Visual Studio and MySQL Connector for .Net?  Nuget alone may not be sufficient, try installing both of these from mysql download website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party tool such as [MySQL Connector]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html to connect a MySQL database to a VS application